# Can't close a hatch after i open it

Tags: unreal-engine4

Im new to Unreal Engine 4 and im trying to make a toilet lid and a fuse box hatch to open and close by pressing E.

Open works fine on both but closing wont work at all. In the float track for the fuse box hatch, i added a start (0 time, 0 value) and end (0.3 time, -120 value).
For the toilet lid i used same start but for end i used same time but -90 in value. It seams that i get the issue when im trying to use a minus value.

Note: Im using the same code i do for doors

I have tried to remove the minus and then it kinda works but the lid and the hatch opens in wrong direction. Thats why i want a minus.

Toilet blueprint Screenshot 
https://i.gyazo.com/27b032fcd92a3545ca713a16b17f2a1d.png

Fuse blueprint Screenshot 
https://i.gyazo.com/013825ae001ca3befe972443f2088ea7.png

Toilet Lid and fuse box hatch should open in correct way and players should be able to open and close.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it might work better (remember to link that flip flip to Play from Start, and not Play, because play will begin at the frame it left off). And also don't create a negative value, because the reverse in the timeline acts like one itself. Example: if your timeline is from float 0 to 5, reverse will subtract that value so -5 basically. Hope it helps. Let me know if this isn't the answer you are looking for :)

[image: Blueprints]